# Is there a way to force a macOS app to open in dark mode when the system is set to light mode?

Tags: themes, dark-mode

Is there a way to open a specific app in dark mode while the rest of the system is set to light mode?

I know the reverse can be done by setting `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance=true` for the app in question, but that just forces it to always use light mode regardless of the system setting, and setting it to false means the app will follow the system theme.

I'm mainly looking for an answer that works back in macOS 10.14 but tricks for later systems would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to open a specific app in dark mode while the rest of the system is set to light mode?

Only if the app supports it.

Dark/Light mode is a systemwide setting, but an app is not required to support it.  Per [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208976):

> Dark Mode uses a dark color scheme that works system wide, including with the apps that come with your Mac. **Apps from other developers can adopt it, too. If an app doesn't use a dark color scheme when Dark Mode is turned on, it doesn't support Dark Mode, or it has its own settings for working with Dark Mode or controlling its color scheme**.

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

If Dark mode is supported by the app and to do what you want, the app would need to support overriding the systemwide dark mode setting and save your choice as a persistent setting in its preferences.